# Trouble with require js shims and r.js

Tags: requirejs, grunt-contrib-requirejs, requirejs-optimizer

I'm having a few issues with r.js I'm hoping someone can shed some light on.

Consider the following shim:

```
shim: {
    plugin: ['jquery'],
    plugin2: ['jquery', 'plugin']
}
```

And the following arbitrary plugins (note: they don't need to be jQuery plugins, but 2 must depend on 1).

Plugin 1:

```
(function ($) {
    $.test = function () {
        console.log('from plugin 1');
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Plugin 2:

```
(function ($) {
    $.test();
})(jQuery);
```

r.js will build the following:

```
(function ($) {
    $.test = function () {
        console.log('from plugin 1');
    }
})(jQuery);
define("plugin", function(){});

(function ($) {
    $.test();
})(jQuery);
define("plugin2", function(){});
```

Which is great - everything is in the correct order.

However, if I need to set

```
wrapShim: true
```

in the build config, I get this as an output:

```
(function(root) {
    define("plugin", [], function() {
        return (function() {
            (function ($) {
                $.test = function () {
                    console.log('from plugin 1');
                }
            })(jQuery);
        }).apply(root, arguments);
    });
}(this));

(function(root) {
    define("plugin2", [], function() {
        return (function() {
            (function ($) {
                $.test();
            })(jQuery);
        }).apply(root, arguments);
    });
}(this));
```

I'm not sure if I'm misreading the point of setting wrapShim to true, but shouldn't this be compiling to:

```
define("plugin", ["jquery"], function() ...
```

and

```
define("plugin2", ["jquery", "plugin"], function() ...
```

?

It appears that wrapShim is totally ignoring dependencies set in the shim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug, fix tracked here:
https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/issues/813

Answer (score 0):

On further inspection while writing this post it appears that if dependencies are listed in the longer form of:

```
shim: {
    plugin: {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    plugin2: {
        deps: ['jquery', 'plugin']
    }
}
```

then the dependencies are injected correctly.